# How to fill column values length same in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Excel Sheet data

```
Eno  EName  Pincode
1     aaa    123456
2     bbb    123423
3     ccc    34
4     ddd     567
5     eee     4532
```

Table Structure

```
  Eno  Varchar(10)
  EName  vachar(25)
  Pincode  Nvarchar(6)
```

I fetch data from excel sheet on the time pincode have 3 or 2 or 6 or 4, I have to check that If pincode column values is less than 6 i have concat 0.

```
 Eg: Pincode 34 it have only 2 digit so i add 4 zero in front 000034.
```

Result

EmpInfo

```
 Eno  EName   PinCode
    1    aaa      123456
    2     bbb     123423 
    3     ccc     000034
    4     ddd     000567
    5      eee    004532
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 1000000 to the `PinCode` value and fetch the 6 rightmost letters.

```
select right(1000000+PinCode, 6)
```

Comment: `PinCode` is `NVARCHAR`, you would be better off adding `'000000'` instead of `1000000`. Otherwise the code is going to go "mysteriously" fail one day with `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1A23' to data type int.`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you wrap this into a scalar-valued function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FormatPinCode 
(
    @rawPin NVARCHAR(6),
    @prefix NVARCHAR(6) = '000000' /* Optional */
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(6)
    SELECT @Result = RIGHT(@prefix + @rawPin, 6)
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Use like this:

```
SELECT Eno, EName, FormatPinCode(PinCode)
```

Comment: Why `NVARCHAR` when it will always be returning a 6 character string? Also you should use `WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`

Comment: NVARCHAR because that's the data type used in the question. Thanks for adding the options... ;)

Comment: Is there any reason you chose `RETURN @Result` instead of simply returning `RETURN RIGHT(@prefix...`?

Comment: @todda.speot.is: Nope, my best excuse is that the code is a draft showing an idea, not final production code... ;) I see your point, and would probably use the abbreviated structure myself...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select 
Eno,
EName,
right('000000' + PinCode, 6) as PinCode
```